# React - how to determine if a specific child component exists?

Tags: reactjs, children

If I have this structure:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <Wrapper />{props.children}</Wrapper>
    );
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
<MyComponent>
    <SomeInnerComponent />
</MyComponent>
```

How can I check to see if `<SomeInnerComponent />` has specifically been included between `<MyComponent></MyComponent>`, from within the `MyComponent` function?

Comment: Do you wanna check whether specifically `SomeInnerComponent` is present or in genral it has some children

Comment: Specifically that `SomeInnerComponent` exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that you want to check that `SomeInnerComponent` is present as a child or not, you could do the following

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    for (let child in props.children){
       if (props.children[child].type.displayName === 'SomeInnerComponent'){
          console.log("SomeInnerComponent is present as a child");
        }  
    }
    return (
        <Wrapper />{props.children}</Wrapper>
    );
}
```

Or you could have a propTypes validation on your component

```
MyComponent.propTypes: {
    children: function (props, propName, componentName) {
      var error;
      var childProp = props[propName];
      var flag = false;

      React.Children.forEach(childProp, function (child) {
        if (child.type.displayName === 'SomeInnerComponent') {
           flag = true
        }
      });
      if(flag === false) {
           error = new Error(componentName + ' does not exist!'
          );
      }
      return error;
    }
  },
```

Comment: Should mention that these methods don't work when using styled components. `displayName` contains `styled.div`.

Comment: Thanks for specifying, I however honestly did not know that and hence I did not mention :)

Comment: Sure, just mentioning it for future reference. If you have the knowledge to do this for styled components, it would be great to have an all-encompassing answer,

Comment: Sure I will check

Comment: Could you try this `child.type.prototype instanceof SomeInnerComponent`

Comment: `child.type` is undefined.

Comment: I mean here `React.Children.forEach(prop, function (child) {
        if (child.type.prototype instanceof SomeInnerComponent) {
           flag = true
        }
      });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149689/discussion-between-joetidee-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: Is there any documentation for the 'type' property on a react element.

Answer (score 2):

React nodes have a `type` property that's set to the constructor, or the function that created the node. So I wrote the following function for checking if a React node was created by a certain  component.

```js
const reactNodeIsOfType = (node, type) =>
    typeof node === "object" && node !== null && node.type === type;
```

Usage:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    let hasInnerComponent = false;

    React.Children.forEach(props.children, (child) => {
        if (reactNodeIsOfType(child, SomeInnerComponent)) {
            hasInnerComponent = true;
        }
    });

    return (
        <>
            <div>hasInnerComponent: {hasInnerComponent ? "yes" : "no"}.</div>
            <Wrapper>{props.children}</Wrapper>
        </>
    );
}
```

```
<MyComponent><div /></MyComponent>
// hasInnerComponent: no

<MyComponent><SomeInnerComponent /></MyComponent>
// hasInnerComponent: yes

const c = <SomeInnerComponent />;
console.log(reactNodeIsOfType(c, SomeInnerComponent));
// true
```

---

This is the TypeScript version. Calling it will also assign the correct type to the node's `props`.

```
const isObject = <T extends object>(value: unknown): value is T =>
    typeof value === "object" && value !== null;

const reactNodeIsOfType = <
    P extends object,
    T extends { (props: P): React.ReactElement | null | undefined }
>(
    node: React.ReactNode,
    type: T
): node is { key: React.Key | null; type: T; props: Parameters<T>[0] } =>
    isObject<React.ReactElement>(node) && node.type === type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to provide an answer for a similar but different need, where you might have an HOC wrapping several layers of components, and you'd like to see if the HOC has already wrapped a component. The method I came up with was to have the HOC add a data-attribute onto the component to serve as a flag, which the HOC could then check on subsequent runs.

```
const WithFoo = Component = props => {
  return props["data-with-foo"]
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : (
      <FooWrapper>
        <Component {...props} data-with-foo />
      </FooWrapper>
    );
};
```