# React component children detect if empty / null before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`"react": "16.8.4"`

Hello, someone knows how to check if there exists children in a (functional) component (before render them)

```
React.Children.count
React.Children.toArray(children)
```

won't work

the children is `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)`

the code example is

```
function ContextMenuItems(): JSX.Element | null {
   if (no-items) return null;  
   ...
}

class ContextMenu extends React.Component {
   public render(): JSX.Element | null {
      if (this.props.children === null) { //ContextMenuItems empty check
        return null;
       }
       return <ContextMenu>{this.props.children}</ContextMenu>
   }
}
```

For any help, idea thankful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - how to determine if a specific child component exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209760/react-how-to-determine-if-a-specific-child-component-exists)

Comment: In that issue the check is on a specific child, here i want to check children count

Comment: @James what are you expecting apart from upvoted answer for the bounty you added? Is your question still for old version of react?

Comment: Hi, @user11243583, take a look to my answer, I think that is what you are looking for

Comment: I had quite some trouble at first to understand the highest voted answer here. Until the penny dropped and I understood that `children.type()` really is just an attempt to call the render function of a single child. I wrote a [blog article](https://dev.to/teetotum/react-dark-magic-devour-your-children-4j90) covering this use case and hopefully did a better job at explaining things. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 27):

#### Solution 1:

Get the children `type`. It will return `null` if `Child` component returns null:

```
const isChildNull = children => {
  return Boolean(children.type()=== null);
};
```

#### Solution 2:

Using [ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup). It converts the `jsx` elements to `string`. If children returns null then `renderToStaticMarkup` will return an empty string:

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

const isChildNull = children => {
  return !Boolean(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(children));
};
```

**Usage:**

```
const Child = () => {
  return null;
};
    
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const isNull = isChildNull(children);
  if (isNull) {
     return "render null";
  }
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};
    
export default function App() {
   return (
     <Parent>
        <Child />
     </Parent>
   );
}
```

[Working example using solution 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ugqtgm)

Comment: in Solution 1, `type` should not be a function, instead `children.type === null`

Comment: @Cameron working example using type as function https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ugqtgm

Comment: errors out for regular html elements, whereas `.type` works for both. Neither works if children is `undefined`

Comment: @Cameron In that case you can check if children is undefined/null first or define a default value.

Comment: `type` for HTML elements is a string, ie. "p", "div".  In that case it's not callable.

`type` for functional components is just the render function. When using `type()` as a function, you are literally just manually rendering it, that's how you can see if it returns `null`.

This won't work for classic components, because `type` is the constructor, so you need to call `new type().render()`.

And neither will work if the component relies on props, as they need to go in as an argument of the function. Plus, skipping the lifecycles could be an issue.

Comment: @JamieGL you should use the solution that fixes to your needs, in that case you can use solution 2

Comment: @lissettdm solution 2 doesn't work if you rely on contexts for example, since `renderToStaticMarkup` isn't aware of them

Answer (score 6):

At the point your parent renders, the children will not have rendered; you only have access to the elements describing them. So, you can check if the element(s) themselves are null or an empty string, as other answers have described. However, if it is a valid element, unfortunately you cannot see if the child's component returns null from its render.

To workaround this, you can manually render it, as @lissettdm has [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396494/1413613). Be warned though, it will render children twice; once manually and once normally as a child. And trying to render via `type()` might often work, but has [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303409/react-component-children-detect-if-empty-null-before-render#comment125174509_64396494). This is not ideal.

#### Hiding via CSS

If it is just that you wish to avoid showing your parent on screen when it renders no children in the DOM; eg. you don't want an empty context menu, then you could consider using simple CSS and targeting your parent with the [`:empty` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty), hiding it that way.

```css
.hidden-if-empty:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```
const ContextMenu = ({ children }) => {
  return <foo className="hidden-if-empty">{children}</foo>
}
```

#### Fallback via CSS

If you need to show a fallback, you can use [CSS content](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/).

Or alternatively, use the [`:only-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child):

```css
.fallback {
  display: none;
}
.fallback-if-empty .fallback:only-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```
const ContextMenu = ({ children }) => (
  <foo className="fallback-if-empty">
    {children}
    <bar className="fallback">Nothing to see here!</bar>
  </foo>
);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can check if the component has children by reading the children prop, along with the [React.Children.count](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrencount) the code would be:

```
function ContextMenuItems({ children }): JSX.Element | null {
   if (!React.Children.count(children)) return null;
   ...
}
```

Comment: The check is in the ContextMenu, before creating the ContextMenu

The check is on _props.children_

React.Children.count wont work for this

Comment: This doesn't work when the child component return null.

Comment: @lissettdm when the child component returns null, it shouldn't be counted as a child right?

Comment: @alextrastero I agree with you, but in this case, if the component has one child that return null, this line React.Children.count(children) will be equal to 1. And the idea is to detect if that child return null, not to count the children

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other solutions, if you want to check if a children is an empty string you can do the following test :

```
!React.isValidElement(children) && children === ""
```

It helped me to do a helper component that could write a text if the component provided as a children is an empty string:

```
const EmptyTextHelper = ({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => !React.isValidElement(children) && children === "" ? (
<span className="italic">No text</span>) : (
<>{children}</>);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an **isValidElement** check before applying React.Children.count as

```
function getValidChildren(children) {
  return React.Children.toArray(children).filter((child) =>
    React.isValidElement(child)
  ) as React.ReactElement[]
}

function ContextMenuItems({ children }): JSX.Element | null {
   if (!React.Children.count(getValidChildren(children))) return null;
   ...
}
```

Comment: This will return false for a string (which is a valid child). It will also return true for an empty fragment, which I think most would consider an empty child.

Answer (score -3):

Should work

```
const hasContent = Boolean(children)
```