# React: wrap child component in div if it does not return null

Tags: reactjs

Using React, how can a child component be wrapped conditionally in another element if it is not returning null when rendered?

```
export const Parent = ({children}) => (
  <div className="row">
    {React.Children.map(children, child =>
      <div className="col-6 col-s-4 col-md-3">
        {child}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

This might be related to the discussions in [React component children detect if empty / null before render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303409/react-component-children-detect-if-empty-null-before-render/64437989#64437989) however, none of the proposed approached seemed to work (ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup seem to have issues with SSR and React.isValidElement is persistently treating the component that returns null as a valid element).
I've got a feeling that this is sort of an anti-pattern, as it seems to be real hard to do. Only solution I can think of at the moment is moving the column div into the child component and clone a prop into the child to inform it that a wrapping column div is desired... Which seems way hacky.

Comment: `if (child) { return (<>wrapped element</>)}` can this help?

Comment: Hi @Naren, thank you for your input. Unfortunately the child itself does exist and is even a valid element. Only when rendered it turns out to be null.

Comment: That a very interesting usecase, can you give a reproducible example you working on? Because the common one already answered, this might help to make one: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-b4cp5?file=/index.js

Comment: What issue ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup have  with SSR?

Comment: Thank you, @lissettdm. It seems the type of the child is just the component one would expect - but it does not tell you if it returns null.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use

```
const isChildNull = children => {
  return !Boolean(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(children));
};
```

try with:

```
const isChildNull = children => {
  return Boolean(children.type() === null); //--> will return the tag type
};
```

If child component receives props, don't forget to pass those props when calling `type` function:

```
const isChildNull = children => {
  const {type, props} = children;
  return Boolean(type(props)=== null);
};
```

**EDIT**: working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a29daw

Comment: Thank you, @lissettdm. This seems to work nice - as long as it is a single child. As far as I can see it stops working when you have children.

Comment: If it have an array of children, you can iterate and check every child one by one.

Comment: @lissettdm second solution does not work, even for single child - try adding some prop like `condition` and returning something else other than `null` if this prop is true - it works only if you always return null

Comment: @pwolaq did you check the working example? please share an example where this code fails.

Comment: @pwolaq the question was about checking if some element return null, if you have a different scenario, please create a new question.

Comment: @lissettdm https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-enrueq

Comment: @pwolaq in that case you need to pass children props...see isChildNull  function here -->https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bqyikg I will update the answer with this details in case of someone else don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @lissettdm ok so you are basically rendering the element twice, first time to check if it returns null and then as a child, at first I thought that you found some kind of workaround for rendering only once

Comment: @pwolaq there is no way to know what function returns before calling it? but you can use React.memo